# jQuery-1.10.2.js yields an error using .hasClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">
```

When I use links with the property 'data-ajax="false"', I want to scroll down the height of the header if the header is visible, by calling the following function, which performs the critical test using the jQuery .hasClass method:

```
  function utHeaderScroll() {
    var h = $('body').pagecontainer(_getActivePage).children('header')[0];
    var y = h.hasClass('ui-fixed-hidden');
    if (y) jQuery.mobile.silentScroll(_0 - h.prop(_scrollHeight));
  }
```

The first line successfully returns the header element for the current page, as shown in this Chrome sources display of Scope Variables:

```
h: header.ui-header.ui-bar-inherit.ui-header-fixed.slidedown
....
```

However, I never get to the scroll operation, because when the function steps into the second line, an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` is immediately raised, and the debugger displays the following code in jquery-1.10.2.js:

```
if ( !(eventHandle = elemData.handle) ) {
    eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
        // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
        // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
        return typeof jQuery !== core_strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
            jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
        undefined;
    };
    // Add elem as a property of the handle fn to prevent a memory leak with IE non-native events
    eventHandle.elem = elem;
}
```

with the 2nd line `("eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e )")` highlighted.

The `y` variable was added to better isolate the problem.  Originally the `hasClass` method was performed in if clause, with the same results.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem, but I've not found it in two days of exploring.

Comment: change $('body').pagecontainer(_getActivePage).children('header')[0]; to $('body').pagecontainer(_getActivePage).children('header').eq(0);

Answer (score 1):

By having the `[0]` at the end of `$('body').pagecontainer(_getActivePage).children('header')[0]`, you're receiving the native DOM object back instead of the jQuery object. It appears you're wanting the first matched element from the array containing all the matched elements. In that case, try one of the following:

Try this:

```
$('body').pagecontainer(_getActivePage).children('header:first')
```

or

```
$('body').pagecontainer(_getActivePage).children('header').first()
```

Remember, jQuery object's are a ***superset*** of the native DOM object. That is, jQuery contains all the native DOM object methods and ***additional*** jQuery specific methods.